# Cannot get YTDL-core to work with discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

Code at: https://github.com/Zentrik/DiscordBot/blob/master/Bot.js

I either get the error:

```
 server.queue.push(args[1]);
                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'queue' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/discordbot/bot.js:133:19)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Client.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/handlers/MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:330:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:293:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/ws/lib/EventTarget.js:99:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:210:7)
```

Or:

```
(node:8565) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
(node:8565) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I got this code from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4S2qqX7YvA

I'm pretty sure the code is the same.

The bot joins the voice channel and has permissions to join and speak.

I'm new to javascript so I don' get what's going wrong any help would be appreciated

EDIT: There was a spelling mistake, I fixed it but now audio finishes right after starting, no sound is produced.

servers[message.guild.id] is `[object Object]`

server.queue[0] is the same url but later adds 'undefined' to the end of the url.

server.dispatcher is also `[object Object]`

Comment: Can you post the code for `bot.js` here? There seems to be a problem around line 133 but the GitHub link you provided only has 67 lines.

Comment: The github link is fine, I just removed unnecessary and personal info. The error is on line 44

Comment: Are you sure? The error says `server.queue.push(args[1]);` but that doesn't appear to be line 44. A more likely candidate is line 47, which has the similar line `servers.queue.push(args[1]);`. I say similar because it's `servers`, not `server`. I suspect the code in GitHub needs to be changed to `server` but that wouldn't explain the error you're seeing, which already says `server`.

Comment: You're right, I've updated the code and I get the second error and an error for the skip command

Comment: Line 8, I believe `despatcher` should be `dispatcher`. The other error I don't understand. What do the values for `message.guild.id` look like?

Comment: The errors have changed, read edit.  The message.guild.id is the same as server id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a problem with the code, as it can works on other machines, thanks for your help. FFMPEG does not work on updated debian systems instead do `sudo apt-get install libav-tools -y`